# Search for a transaction

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql-injection

Could you have a quick look over my code to see if it's safe from SQL injection etc.. and suggest any amendments?

```
<html>
<head><title>Retrieve Your Login Code</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor=#ffffff>

<?php

echo "<h2>Search Results:</h2><p>";

//If they did not enter a search term we give them an error
if ($find == "")
{
echo "<p>You forgot to enter a search term!!!";
exit;
}

// Otherwise we connect to our Database
mysql_connect("server.com", "ipn", "pw!") or     die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("ipn") or die(mysql_error());

// We perform a bit of filtering
$find = strtoupper($find);
$find = strip_tags($find);
$find = trim ($find);

//Now we search for our search term, in the field the user specified
$iname = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ibn_table WHERE itransaction_id = '$find'");

//And we display the results
while($result = mysql_fetch_array( $iname ))
{
echo "<b>Name: </b>";
echo $result['iname'];
echo " "; 
echo "<br>";
echo "<b>E-mail: </b>";
echo $result['iemail'];
echo "<br>";
echo "<b>Transaction Date: </b>";
echo $result['itransaction_date'];
vecho "<br>";
echo "<b>Payment Amount: &pound</b>";
echo $result['ipayerid'];
echo "<br>";
//And we remind them what they searched for
echo "<b>Search Term </b>(Transaction ID): </b> " .$find;
//}
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
echo "<b>Login Code: </b>";
echo $result['ipaymentstatus'];
echo "<br>";
}

//This counts the number or results - and if there wasn't any it gives them a little     message explaining that
$anymatches=mysql_num_rows($iname);
if ($anymatches == 0)
{
echo "Sorry, but we can not find an entry to match your search, please make sure the     correct details have been entered...<br><br>";
}


?> 


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: mysql_connect (and related) are depreciated in PHP v5.5 http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php You should switch to use mysqli or more preferably a PDO system. This alone will greatly help against SQL injection.

Comment: Could you not take the time to at least properly indent your code before asking others to proofread it?

Answer (score 6):

Really this won't be safe unless you use parameterized queries, which allow the database to combine the query in the form that is safest.

See the [PHP docs for mysqli.prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)
and [this helpful article](http://mattbango.com/notebook/code/prepared-statements-in-php-and-mysqli/)

Also, just for your own sanity, I'd try separating your PHP from your HTML. You might want to look into a templating system as well, like Smarty, just to make your code easier to manage in the long run.

Answer (score -1):

```
// We perform a bit of filtering
$find = strtoupper($find);
$find = strip_tags($find);
$find = trim ($find);
$find = mysql_real_escape_string($find);
```

one more step and you are safer. I recommend using `PDO` or `mysqli` to prevent sql injection completely.

If you are not learning PHP and mySQL, but creating an application, I recommend using framework like symfony or lavarel instead :)

Comment: Thanks for that, ived added in the last string. How do i use mysqli insted? im very very new to all this.

Comment: So you are learning about PHP and mySQL. I suggest you searching in Stackoverflow to find a good way to starting learning PHP and MYSQL :)

You can start from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610543/recommended-way-to-learn-php

Comment: ok, so with that string added, it should be safe enough?

Comment: my code assumes that register_globals is turned on, how do i change it to make it work with register_globals off??

Comment: yes it is ;) 
@MarcJones put another question on stackoverflow :)

Comment: @MarcJones don't forget to vote the answer and mark it as accepted :)

Comment: Why was that downvoted?

Comment: @MarcJones I had to check the year on this… `register_globals`!? Holy crap. :) In answer to your question, it depends where `find` comes from. If the search form has `method="GET"`, you retrieve it with `$find = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'find', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);`. If the method is `POST` then it's `INPUT_POST` instead. That filter also strips tags, by the way.